Pycharm VCS>share project to GitHub created the repository but wont push my local files
Hi all sorry if someone already asked but I couldn't find an answer. I'm also fairly new to GitHub and how it works.
I did a Django project on my local machine fairly finished with it and wanted to push it on my GitHub. I used PyCharm if it makes any difference.
So I went to top menu bar in PyCharm  VCS>share project to GitHub  and named my repository added a description and shared like I have done a few times before with other projects. This created the repository on my profile fine but it created an empty repository. In my PyCharm my files are orange but when i go to commit there is nothing to commit I cant chose any files to commit or push.

I'm not sure is it because there are so many files since its a Django app that its struggling to push it?
and the Version control only seems to have created the local master there is no remote in PyCharm. I cant add it manually to the Repository since there are to many files. I know in the future to create a repo from the start now but is there a way to sort this out so it syncs to the repo and actually pushes the files.
I tried to push my project to GitHub trough PyCharm and was expecting a repository to be created and my files to be pushed on to the repository.

Red means you aren't tracking any of those files yet - 4,976 unversioned files. I'd strongly recommend not doing all of the work then thinking about version control next time.

@jonrsharpe Ah I see so I need to add all the files to track. Thank you. And yes i made a mistake I wasn't going to post this on GitHub as it was initially just a follow along but wanted to keep it as a reference in the end. Learned my lesson now will just upload everything and private in the future.

Even if you don't push to a remote, tracking it locally and making commits means you can undo to a known-good point if you make a mistake etc.
